# resize many different images with different sizes

Tags: batch, images, adobe-photoshop, jpeg

I have a large selection of jpeg that are all different shapes/sizes (450 x 60 pixels, 800 X 200 pixels etc).

I am trying to batch resize them (there are many) using automate/batch on Photoshop (I use a mac). I would like to have them all at 200 x 200 pixels without affecting each individual image size (as in keep their aspect ratios)

Comment: Vote to close because a similar question has been answered before on StackExchange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456998/a-batch-script-to-resize-images

Comment: As per the linked dupe, http://www.bricelam.net/ImageResizer/ is your friend for this. I've used it many times in the past.

Comment: Apologies, edited with updated info,

Comment: Can you change a 450 x 60 to 200 x 200 w/o changing it's aspect ratio?